# WPF MaterialDesign SolidColorBrush Value Conflict

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, material-design-in-xaml

I am using Material Design to style my WPF app. I have used the following code to style a tab view:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <!-- Material Design -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Dark.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />

            <!-- Styles -->
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Dark.xaml" />-->
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

                <!-- Tab Controller Primary Styles -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightBrush" Color="#212121"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightForegroundBrush" Color="#212121"/>

                    <!-- This causes a clash between the tabview and the textbox colors -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="#212121"/>
                    <!--<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="#BB86FC"/>-->
                

                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkBrush" Color="#212121"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkForegroundBrush" Color="#212121"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>

            

            <!-- Tab Controller Secondary Styles -->
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryAccentBrush" Color="#BB86FC"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryAccentForegroundBrush" Color="#BB86FC"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Dragablz;component/Themes/materialdesign.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type dragablz:TabablzControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTabablzControlStyle}" />
        
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

The issue I have is that to style the TabController primary style, it changes the color of the TextBox in my application.

When I apply a dark color to style the tab view, the TextBox loses its purple highlight.

[image: The tab view is styled correctly but because of the dark color, the TextBox is no longer purple]

[image: The tab view is now wrong, but the TextBox is correct]

But now in the second image, when I change the color back to purple for the TextBox, the TabView looks horrific.

They both depend on the same dictionary key for their styles. Is there a way I can change the x:Key value depending on what object type it is applied to? What is the best way to preserve the styles I need for both components.

This is for my university dissertation so I appreciate the help!

All the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Material Design brushes are used in various styles of controls using `DynamicResource`. That means if you replace or register a brush with the same `x:Key` at runtime, all dynamic references will be adapted and the change will be applied to all controls in scope of the resource dictionary where you defined it.

In general, you would have to copy the default style and template for the control that you want to apply the changed color to and adapt it, e.g. by creating a separate brush and using it instead of the original, given the values are assigned in the control template directly instead of template bindings.

In case of the `TabablzControl` there might be an easier way. From its [default style at GitHub](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/Dragablz/blob/master/Dragablz/Themes/MaterialDesign.xaml), I can only see one usage of `PrimaryHueMidBrush` that is set as `BorderBrush` in a `Setter`. You can ovewrite this in your style.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type dragablz:TabablzControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTabablzControlStyle}">
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#212121"/>
</Style>
```

Of course, you could create a custom brush and reference it via `DynamicResource` instead of hardcoding it.

```
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource MyCustomPrimaryHueMidBrush}"/>
```